# Ubertesters won't recognize my devices as provisioned

Tags: ios, provisioning, ubertesters

- Ubertesters says my device is not provisioned http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/VBW8
- The UDID matches the one listed on all of my provisioning profiles on `developer.apple.com`. See http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/VBPQ and http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/VBGt
- I'm not sure what to do to get it to recognize that the devices are listed in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you generate provision at developer.apple.com and download it. Then click twice on profile so it will be automatically installed. 
After that make ipa file. When Organizer will ask you about Provisioning Profile be sure to choose the newest profile.

As for me I have 2 provisioning profiles with the same name. I chose the last one.
[image]

Comment: Yep, I have the correct prov profile for the app and the target. Do I need to `Save for Enterprise Distribution` ?

Comment: I've tried with the the following profiles, `Ad Hoc`, `App Store Official`, `iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *`, and `iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.myappname`

Comment: Yes you need to save for enterprize distribution. You can do it with Ad Hoc provision and with development provision.
Kirk, do your UDIDs starts with FFFF or not?